# Multiple Inline declaration vs Reuse of variables

Tags: performance, delphi, variable-declaration, delphi-10.3-rio

Having a procedure with alot of blocks of nested for-loops ex. one block 
could look like this

```
for a := 0 to x do
  //Do something
  for b := 0 to x do
    for c := 0 to a do
      //Do something
```

Is there any penalty in declaring all the loop variables in each for-loop like

```
for var a := 0 to x do  
  for var b := 0 to x do
    for var c := 0 to a
```

Or should they be declared once at the top and reused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the inline. It's tidier and the compiler should optimize it.